# Are there any Stack Exchange site where I can ask practical and subjective questions?

Tags: discussion

I wonder if there are any Stack Exchange site where I can ask general, possibly subjective questions. These may not be strictly about programming, but practical good to think of questions. An example can be following which I am thinking about right now.

"I need to download some library for charts and plotting for Java. Does anyone know if you get malware by downloading it (since it is located on the sourceForge repo)."

This is a realistic question, since I do not want malware on my computer. However, the question is rather if it fits in the SE scope.

I know similar questions have been written before, but this one is meant to include both questions like the example and also library recommendations (guess no example is required here). So general head scratchings about programming, so to say.

Comment: Not on StackExchange. But you can try Quora, or Yahoo Answers.

Comment: To be fair, even if you pulled a download link from a reputable site not known for malware, there is _still_ the risk of getting malware with your download. _"Does anyone know if you get malware by downloading it"_ isn't really a great question for our site, mainly because it's hard to definitively answer that question. I've seen cases where two people download something from the same place at the same time, but only one of them got malware. (And boy was my friend mad at me when she found out I got a clean download.)

Comment: @Kendra that was kind of the point. I know it is hard to give a good answer since the answer would probably depend on rumors. However, I guess I get your point. SE network requires questions which can give a definite answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does anyone know if you get malware by downloading [something from some site]

You're asking the wrong question. Your original problem is *"I do not want malware on my computer"*. So the proper question is:

> How can I prevent getting malware on my computer?

To which the answer will be:

> Install malware and virus detection software on your computer.

You would have gotten exactly that answer if you would have asked the latter question on the [Software Recommendations beta](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) subsite.

The original question is unanswerable because maybe that particular download at this specific time is not "upgraded" by SourceForge with an extra installer, but it may be at the moment you click one of the many Download buttons. Or maybe some downloaders do get their downloads with a little extra, while others don't. Nobody can tell you but the SF staff, and they surely won't.

Comment: I honestly did not know about the Software recommendations site. So can I assume that your point is that rumors does not belong on SE network?

Comment: @patrik all I'm saying is that questions that don't have a definitive answer don't belong on the SE network. The question as you stated is not answerable.