# Where would it be appropriate to post a question in SO about carpal tunnel preventive measures for programmers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My first instinct was to ask the question:

> What do you do to try to prevent carpal tunnel syndrome?

in `Programmers` or `SO`, because:

1. Carpal Tunnel Syndrome is something that is likely to affect programmers (due to a lot of typing)
2. I suspect that many of us take active measure to prevent Carpal Tunnel and thus have many neat tricks and tips (personal opinion 1)
3. Answer to this question might provide information that might be beneficial to all (personal opinion 2)

But I hesitate to ask such a question in `Programmers` or `SO`, because it is not a question about programming or SW development, but pertains to the programmer's lifestyle.

Where would the above question be appropriate?

Comment: I would check out the StackExchange [health.se] site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any Stack Exchange site where I can ask practical and subjective questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302174/are-there-any-stack-exchange-site-where-i-can-ask-practical-and-subjective-quest)

Comment: @gnat carpal tunnel related questions are hardly "subjective" like the duplicate you linked to.  It's a well-defined medical condition that afflicts many people, especially those working at a computer.  It's certainly off-topic on SO, but it is answerable and fairly specific.

Comment: @ryanyuyu duplicate question isn't focused on strictly subjective questions. Its title is slightly confusing but the text inside makes it clear that asker is primarily interested in practical aspects: "I wonder if there are any Stack Exchange site where I can ask general, possibly subjective questions. These may not be strictly about programming, but practical good to think of questions..."

Comment: @gnat the linked duplicate is overly broad.  It tried to shotgun two completely different types of questions.  Questions that are practical are distinct from questions that are general/possibly subjective.  More importantly, this question has a different answer than the duplicate target.  This one's answer is _try health.SE_ and the target's answer is "_The original question is unanswerable_."

Comment: @ryanyuyu if you re-read this very question, it fits there, "What do you do to blah blah... many neat tricks and tips" etc etc. ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @gnat while I can see some aspect of a "list question" and possibly broad, it's objectively answerable.  For example, an occupational therapist or ergonomics expert would be able to point to specific risk factors that a programmer could mitigate on their own.

Comment: @ryanyuyu but the question asked about here doesn't seek an input from _professionals_, it simply polls the programmers, "What do you do to blah blah... many neat tricks and tips"

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131733/213575

Answer (score 11):

You are correct, it would be off topic on SO or Programmers because it's not about programming, it's about typing.  It is a problem that some programmers face, but it's also a problem faced by lots of other people in lots of other professions.

You can ask questions about carpal tunnel syndrome (for any/all professions) on https://health.stackexchange.com/

See https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carpal-tunnel-syndrome

Comment: I would, however, post a note and a link to your question in chats on BOTH SO and Programmers.

Comment: @LIttleAncientForestKami: No. Don't spam chat with random links to sortof-relevant questions. Besides, what chat would you link it in? There isn't a single room out there that has enough coverage to make it worth the spam.

Comment: @Cerbrus, while I respect your opinion, I disagree (on basis that this question and discussion that may arise of it is not a spam, not to programmers, who are likely victims of said syndrome). Still, let's leave it up to votes on our respective comments - that's a clear indicator what programming folks frequenting SO think. :-)

Comment: What room would you chose then? I can almost guarantee they won't appreciate it if a random question from a different network is dumped in there.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, health.SE is a potential home for your question topic.  However, as [gnat has pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321424/where-would-it-be-appropriate-to-post-a-question-in-so-about-carpal-tunnel-preve?noredirect=1#comment335479_321424), your question currently reads like a water-cooler question instead of a specific question.  Specifically, your second point

> I suspect that many of us take active measure to prevent Carpal Tunnel and thus have many neat tricks and tips (personal opinion 1)

completely smells of a list/recommendation question which is off-topic on most SE sites.

With a few more details though, you can edit the question into an objectively answerable question.  For example, if you addressed specific aspects of carpal-tunnel prevention (like posture, changes in work enviroment/habits, preventative exercises) then people knowledgeable in ergonomics or occupational therapy could offer specific advice.  A more specific, answerable question might read like

> I program for N hours a day, which involves a lot of typing.  What things can I change/habits can I learn at work to lower my risk of carpal tunnel?